# Would Bekenstein bound disappear in some holographic models?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, boundary-conditions, ads-cft, holographic-principle

In Holographic principle models there's a limit to the information that the system can store known as the "Bekenstein bound".

> In physics, the Bekenstein bound is an upper limit on the entropy S, or information I, that can be contained within a given finite region of space which has a finite amount of energy—or conversely, the maximum amount of information required to perfectly describe a given physical system down to the quantum level

But if we have a theoretically infinite holographic boundary or system, then, would Bekenstein bound "disappear"? Could it save infinite information then?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking if we set a limit to be at infinity, then would that limit effectively disappear.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Nat basically yes: Like, if we had a bowl of water of 2L of capacity we could fill it with 2L of water. But if that bowl was infinite in size, then, there would be no limit for the amount of water we could fit there and we could fill it with infinite liters of water. Would it be the same for the holographic principle?

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/223170/